# Climbing Stairs and finding all possible combinations of stairs, 1 and 2 at a time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, closures, memoization

There are a lot of helpful threads on this in other languages but I am having a hard time finding a good one in JavaScript. The code below works but for the life of me I cant figure out why. I understand the basics of recursion but this one is stumping me. It seems to me that each recursive calling of resolve would just place the resulting sum in an index that has nothing to do with the final call to `memory[n]`. If there are other resources on this problem in JavaScript I would greatly appreciate that as well!

```
var climbStairs = function(n) {
  let result = resolve(n, []);
  return result;
};

function resolve(n, memory) {
  if (memory[n]) {
    return memory[n];
  }
  if (n == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  let result = resolve(n - 1, memory) + resolve(n - 2, memory);
  memory[n] = result;
  return result;
}

console.log(climbStairs(44));
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a quintessential example of dynamic programming. The solution for the entire problem depends on the solution for subproblems, which also depend on subproblems, and so on. A particular subproblem may need to be calculated more than once, so the above you showed stores it in an array the first time it is calculated, so the next time the value is needed, it will only require a constant time array index lookup.

This may help you understand:

```js
function resolve(n, memory) {
  if (memory[n]) {
    console.log(n, "already calculated");
    return memory[n];
  }
    console.log("calculating for", n);
  if (n == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  let result = resolve(n - 1, memory) + resolve(n - 2, memory);
  memory[n] = result;
  return result;
}

var climbStairs = function(n) {
  let result = resolve(n, []);
  return result;
};

climbStairs(10);
```